# Problem with CLGeocoder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync in Xamarin

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, maps

I am currently looking into (existing) solution for iOS under Xamarin. I have a map with following code:

```
public override async Task<string> ResolveLatLngToAddress(double lat, double lng, MapAddressFormat addressFormat) 
        {
            var geocoder = new CLGeocoder();

            try 
            {
                var placemarks = await geocoder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync(new CLLocation(lat, lng));

                if (placemarks.Length > 0)
                {
                    var placemark = placemarks[0];

                    switch (addressFormat) 
                    {
                        case MapAddressFormat.AddressFormatFull: 
                            {
                            return FormatUtils.Join(true, placemark.Name, placemark.Locality, placemark.SubLocality);
                            }
                        case MapAddressFormat.AddressFormatNoNumber: 
                            {
                                return FormatUtils.Join(true, placemark.Thoroughfare, placemark.Locality, placemark.SubLocality);
                            }
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Foundation.NSErrorException e) 
            {
                // Unable to find a location with the supplied latitude and longitude

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The code works really well when user moves the pin around, there is a textbox control that displays currently selected address. Once the user starts zooming in and out however, the application breaks and the function stops working.

I have done some research and I understand that CLGeocoder class works in a way that if the users starts too many requests, the response slows down and then stops completely (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder).

I can see that the problem is that the event is triggered multiple times during the zoom, e.g. zooming in triggers for example 20 requests for location resolution.

I would to trigger the location resolution only after the user finished zooming, is it possible to achieve somehow, for example with delayed binding?

Please note that I am new to both iOS development and Xamarin.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Showing the zooming code that is calling ResolveLatLngToAddress would be helpful as just the ResolveLatLngToAddress method provides no context to the "zoom finished"

Comment: a simple approach would be to store the timestamp every time you make a request, and when a new request is attempted, only send it if it has been more than X seconds since the last request

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comments. I have eventually solved it by caching previously queried location and re-querying only if the lat/lng coordinates changed by certain margin which I estimated to be 1 meter (perfectly fine for my purposes).

```
private double _cached_lat = 999;
    private double _cached_lng = 9999;
    private string _cached_location = "";

    public override async Task<string> ResolveLatLngToAddress(double lat, double lng, MapAddressFormat addressFormat) 
    {
        double latDif = System.Math.Abs(_cached_lat - lat);
        double lngDif = System.Math.Abs(_cached_lng - lng);

        //precission - around 1m
        double geo_precission = 0.000005;

        if (((System.Math.Abs (_cached_lat - lat) < geo_precission) && (System.Math.Abs (_cached_lng - lng) < geo_precission)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cached_location))) 
        {
            return _cached_location;
        }

        var geocoder = new CLGeocoder();
```